# Event for all Controls (Textbox)

Tags: textbox, vb6

I have many textboxes in my form and all of it have keypress.

Is there another way to shorten by code instead writing the code for each texboxes?

Thank You for your Answer.

Comment: Use a *Control Array* or http://www.thescarms.com/VBasic/SubClassTxt.aspx

Comment: Yes, this is one of the reasons why we have control arrays.  You can always pretty up your code by using an Enum to give friendly names to the index values of the members of the control array.

Comment: Thank for your answers. It helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a subclass (let's call it subTB) of TextBox in which you define the action for keyPressed. Then make your TextBox be instances of subTB instead of instances of TextBox. You have a link to a tutorial in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49817472/event-for-all-controls-textbox#comment86649625_49817472).

Or you can create a function that contains the action to perform when a key is pressed. And the in all your textBox, on the key pressed event, call this function. This second choice will make you also write multiple time the same but this same code will just be a call to the function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. i will try your answer

Comment: Looking at that link, it is not actually a "subclass" but rather a wrapper.